# css/javascript to determine width of text or word vs. width of block element

Tags: css, width

We have some application which present text on cell phones.  Some of the divs would have styling something like this:

```
width:150px;
text-align:center;
overflow:hidden;
```

It occurs to me that it would be nice to determine whether the width of any individual word within that div exceeded the width of its container, at least to alert customer support they should abbeviate it or do a workaround.  Is there any way to do that?  One idea I had was using PHP to wrap each word in a <span> tag, but I'd prefer something native to the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what text size you're using? You could always use vw units or em units. Em's are like a percentage of the original, e.g.:

```
.original{font-size:20px;}
.original.em2{font-size:2em;}/*would be 40px*/
.original.em1{font-size:1em;}/*would be 20px*/
```

vw units or view point units are also handy. I use them to keep font sizes as a percentage almost

```
.vw{font-size:5vw;}/*5% width */
```

Although there may be browser compatibility issues. 
Always use a fallback :)

Here's some links:

**vw:**

http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units

https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/

**ems:**

http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-email-tel-url